# Botão que envia email para entrar em contato com o desenvolvedor

Tags: java, android

Como faço para criar um botão que ao usuário clicar ele envia um e-mail para outro e-mail pré definido?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode criar um `Intent` e inserir dentro do método `setOnClickListener()` do botão. Vide comentários. Veja um exemplo:

```
Button btnSendEmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendEmail);

btnSendEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         // cria um intent 
         Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         // define o email especifico pre definido
         String[] recipients = new String[] {
             "emailespecifico@email.com"
         };
         // insere o email no extra
         emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
         // define um assunto 
         emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Aqui o assunto");
         // define o conteúdo do email
         emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Conteúdo do email");
         // definido o tipo 
         emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
         // inicia o intent
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Enviar email..."));
     }
 });
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSendEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enviar email"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Veja mais na [documentação sobre `Intent`'](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)s.

Comment: Como vínculo esse intent ao meu botão?

Comment: @Paiva editei para melhor entendimento.